# Can Sidekiq be performed for more than 1 task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, sidekiq

we have already used sidekiq for inserting records into our table asynchronously  and we very often check production sidekiq dashboard to monitor no. of processed, queued, retry, busy for inserting records.

And we have got a new requirement to delete records (say users tables : delete expired users) asynchronously. we also need to monitor sidekiq dashboard for processes, queued, retry very often.

For insert records we use :

In my User controller:

```
def create_user
   CreateUserWorker.perform_async(@client_info, @input_params)
end
```

In my lib/workers/createuser_worker.rb

```
class CreateUserWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(client_info, input_params)
    begin
      @client_info = client_info
      @user = User.new(@client_info)
      @user.create(input_params)
    rescue
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

If I do the same for delete users asynchronously using sidekiq, how can i differentiate inserted process with deleted process without any messup?

Answer (score 0):

First, If you want to check error for creating in begin-rescue block, you should use create! method. not create method.

Create method do not raise error.

Check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html)

Destroy method is same to Create method.
Use destroy method with ! ([destroy!](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy))

Of course, You should add new worker for destroy user.
because perform method should exists only 1. 
If you do not want to add new worker, try pattern below!

```
UserWorker
  def perform(~, flag)
    #flag meaning is create or destroy
    is_success = false # result of creating or destroying
    # create or destroy
    # ..
    # ..

    LogModel.create({}) # user info with is_success and flag
  end
ebd
```

P.S
I think create() next new() is some awkward(?). 
I recommend

```
@user = User.create(client_info)
```

or

```
@user = User.new(client_info)
@user.save! (bang meaning is same to above)
```

And no need begin-rescue block. Just use Create, Destroy method with bang.

```
def perform(client_info, input_params)
  User.create!(client_info) # if failed raise Error 
end
```

#### ++Added for comments

I think if you have many user deleted or destroyed, pass **user_ids (or user_infos) array** to Worker perform method and in perform method, loop creating or destroying (if there is failed record created or destroyed, create log file or log model entry about a failed record).

If all user_id must be created or destroyed at once, use transaction block.

```
def perform(params)
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
      # loop create or destroy
    end
  rescue 
  end
end
```

if not, just loop

```
def perform(params)
  #loop
  if Create or destroy method (without bang)
    #success
  else
    #failed
  end  
end
```

XWorker.perform_async() method maybe is called from admin page(?).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, glad that I had some learnings. I would follow up the code principles. :) 
I have to delete around 100k records to delete from table and I need to perform asynchronous (sidekiq). I need to loop through records to be deleted. In this scenario,where i need to call "perform" method?